# CodeCeption seeInDatabase showing pass when the query does not return any results

Tags: php, codeception

Inside Project\tests\acceptance\TestCept.php I have something like:

```
<?php
$I = new WebPerson($scenario);

$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $today;

$I->wantTo('Test');

$I->seeInDatabase('email',['Emailid' => '1'], ['EmailSubject' => 'Test'], ['SendDate' => $today]);
```

I run:

```
codecept run acceptance --steps
```

I get:

```
* I see in database "Email",{"Emailid":"1"},{"EmailSubject":"Test"},{"SendDate":"2014-04-01 22:28:11"}
PASSED
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM email WHERE emailid= '1' AND EmailSubject='Test' AND SendDate = "2014-04-01 22:28:11";
```

I get zero results.

What am I overlooking? Why does CodeCeption return a PASS when no records exist for this query?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeInDatabese() method should get only two arguments! You pass your WHERE criteria as three separate arrays, so only the first would be passed to SELECT query.

You should write:

```
$I->seeInDatabase('email',['Emailid' => '1', 'EmailSubject' => 'Test', 'SendDate' => $today]);
```